# How to make MS Access display carriage returns (in a single text field) properly on a report

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS Access table with field named "Instructions" that uses Long Text as field type. When editing the field on a form I designed, I enter "enter"/ carriage returns so it looks the way I want it to.

Example:

```
Steps:
1. Open Program
2. Open File Menu
3. Click Open Recent File
4. Select Desired File
```

It looks fine while the field is displayed in the text box on my form however when I generate a report which I intend to print. The data instead is displayed as follows:

```
Steps: 1. Open Program 2. Open File Menu 3. Click Open Recent File 4. Select Desired File
```

I have tried using the following script (triggered on button click:

```
Me.[Instructions] = Replace(Me.Instructions, Chr(10), Chr(13) & Chr(10))
```

however it either doesn't work (when the button is in the form where I edit the text box) or returns me with Run-time error 2448 - You cant Assign a value to this object

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Strange, this should work without any problems. Make sure your textbox on the report has `Can grow` = Yes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to update the value of a field in the select query that's powering your report. And that's probably why you get the runtime error.

Could could always create a hidden textbox (`Visible = No`) on the report, put the updated value in there and then base the textbox that is displaying `me.instructions` off of on that other hidden textbox instead.

It might be "cleaner" to use a little function call on the report to populate the visible textbox instead of using the hidden one.